# Get partial response API get request

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, get

I have a JSON response which is really heavy and it is not needed to load the whole response object in the beginning. So, I would like to get only **partial response** with query parameter in the get request.

I am testing this with POSTMAN application. I have the response like the following

```
{
    "user": {
         "name": "blah",
         "email": "blah@blah.com"
     },
     "contracts": [
         {"id": 1 },
         {"id: 2"}
      ]
}
```

Here, I would like to get only **user** inside the JSON response and not **contracts**

I tried the following ways

```
//api-request-url?fields=user
```

But this is returning the entire JSON object. Can anyone help to get just **user** as response.

Comment: The response is handled by the backend, so if the backend doesnt have anything to filter the response it will just send what it can. Have you implemented anything backend specifically? Json-api, graphql?

Comment: thanks for the response. I found that nothing is implemented in backend to support this. So, this won't work.